# Getting Objects by id in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to get data by id in my django app. The problem is that I don't know the kind of id the user will click on. I tried adding the below code in my views but I'm getting this error:

```
 ValueError at /findme/

 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'

 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/findme/
 Django Version:    1.4
 Exception Type:    ValueError
 Exception Value:   invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'id'

 Exception Location:    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 537
 Python Executable:     C:\Python27\python.exe
  Python Version:   2.7.3
```

Views

```
from meebapp.models import Meekme

def cribdetail(request):
    post=Meekme.objects.get(id='id')
    return render_to_response('postdetail.html',{'post':post, 'Meekme':Meekme},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `'id'` is a string and you need to pass an integer here:

```
post=Meekme.objects.get(id='id')
```

It should most likely look like this:

```
def cribdetail(request, meekme_id):
    post=Meekme.objects.get(id=meekme_id)
    return render_to_response('postdetail.html',{'post':post, 'Meekme':Meekme},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

where `meekme_id` is an integer that is part of the URL. Your URL configuration should contain:

```
url(r'^example/(?P<meekme_id>\d+)/$', 'example.views.cribdetail'),
```

When you visit `example/3/`, that means Django will call the view `cribdetail` with the value 3 assigned to `meekme_id`. See the Django [URL documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) for more details.

Comment: After following your instruction, I'm getting this error: NoReverseMatch at /search/

Reverse for 'meebapp.views.cribdetail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.  Urlconf: url(r'^cribme/(?P<meekme_id>\d+)/$', 'meebapp.views.cribdetail'),  In Models:  def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('meebapp.views.cribdetail', (),[str(self.id)]) In Template: <a href="{% url meebapp.views.cribdetail %}"> What I'm I missing?

Comment: @picomon: In that case you're giving incorrect parameters to the reverse function of Django. You need to make sure that the name and values for reversing a URL are correct and that there is indeed a URL with that name and those parameters.

Comment: Can I input id alone in the parameters? BTW: Do check my edit in the above comment.

Comment: Change the `get_absolute_url` to the following: `return ('meebapp.views.cribdetail', (), {'meekme_id': self.id})`. Also, in the template you need to add the id, so it would be `{% url meebapp.views.cribdetail post.id %}`.

Comment: another error: NoReverseMatch at /search/

Reverse for 'meebapp.views.cribdetail' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Comment: kindly check out my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264655/valueerror-when-getting-objects-by-id

Answer (score 1):

the error message is saying 'id' is integer
but you are passing string .

Comment: You have to pass id as integer. Simeon write for example only.