# ValueError when getting objects by id

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to get data by id in my django app. The problem is that I don't know the kind of id the user will click on. I input the below codes in views.

Views

```
def cribdetail(request, meekme_id):
    post=Meekme.objects.get(id=meekme_id)
    return render_to_response('postdetail.html',{'post':post, 'Meekme':Meekme},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Urlconf

```
url(r'^cribme/(?P<meekme_id>)\d+/$', 'meebapp.views.cribdetail', name='cribdetail'),
```

In template:

```
<a href="{% url cribdetail post.id %}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
```

When I click on the above link in my template, I'm getting the below error:

```
ValueError at /cribme/0/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cribme/0/
Django Version:     1.4
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 537
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.3
```

Been fighting with this for a while now. How can I get rid of that error?

Comment: duplicate of [Getting Objects by id in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259322/getting-objects-by-id-in-django)

Comment: @DanielRoseman: not quite, different problem here, the regular expression has an error in it (empty group).

Comment: In addition, its actually not a good idea to use the 'get' method directly to get the object. Best practice would be to use the django shortcut get_object_or_404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks to me that your urlconf is to blame, it should be:

```
url(r'^cribme/(?P<meekme_id>\d+)/$', 'meebapp.views.cribdetail', name='cribdetail'),
```

not:

```
url(r'^cribme/(?P<meekme_id>)\d+/$', 'meebapp.views.cribdetail', name='cribdetail'),
```

`?P<meekme_id>` means "give the matched string between parentheses this name. () matches nothing, which is why your app give an error when trying to look up the item with id `''`.

When the parentheses enclose the `\d+`, you match a natural number, which should work.

Answer (score 1):

The regex in your urlconf needs a little tweak:

```
url(r'^cribme/(?P<meekme_id>\d+)/$', 'meebapp.views.cribdetail', name='cribdetail'),
```

The value of the `meekme_id` parameter wasn't being captured, since the `\d+` was outside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced a closing parenthesis:

```
url(r'^cribme/(?P<meekme_id>\d+)/$', 'meebapp.views.cribdetail', name='cribdetail'),
```

Note that the `(?P<meekme_id> .. )` group construct should include the `\d+` characters you are trying to match. In your incorrect regular expression you define a group that doesn't include any matched characters, thus always the empty string `''`.

Comment: You guys rock!!! Thanks so much.. @Daniel result.object.id works.. Once again.. Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the URL problem, you are not generating the right link in the first place - you refer to `result.object.title` but `post.id` in the template, which is why your URL contains 0 for the ID. I expect you mean `result.id` or `result.object.id`.