# Editing without using id hidden field in form?

Tags: django

I am not sure if this is the cleanest way of writing an edit. But after hours of research this is the best I could come up with. However I don't like the fact that I have to store the id inside a hiddenfield just to retrieve it again as POST to actually update the model.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
def edit_contact_view(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if 'id' in request.GET:
        try:
            id = request.GET['id']
            contacts = profile.company.contact_set.all()
            form = ContactsForm(profile.company, instance=contacts.get(id=id))
            form.data['id'] = id
            variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form })
            return render_to_response("contact.html", variables)
        except Contact.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404(_(u'Contact not found'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactsForm(profile.company, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                contacts = profile.company.contact_set.all()
                contact = contacts.get(id=form.cleaned_data['id'])
                contact.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                contact.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Firstly, in Django it's more usual to pass the id in the URL itself, rather than in a GET parameter - eg `/contact/edit/3/` rather than `/contact/edit?id=3`. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264655/valueerror-when-getting-objects-by-id) to see how to configure URLs like that.

Secondly, whichever way you do it, there's no need to pass the id in a hidden variable since it's already available from the URL. You can always get the instance from there.

Thirdly, I presume that `ContactForm` is a ModelForm, but you're not using the `save` functionality, which simplifies things still further.

Putting it all together:

```
def edit_contact_view(request, id=None):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if id is not None:
        contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=id)
    else:
        contact = Contact(company=profile.company)
    if request.POST:
       form = ContactForm(request.POST, instance=contact)
       if form.is_valid():
           contact = form.save()
           return redirect(...)

    else:
        form = ContactForm(instance=contact)
    return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: thanks a lot Daniel, this solution is very clean and complete. I have implemented all your three suggestions and it works beautifully. So much shorter and it combines both add & edit in one. The only thing is  when I add a `Contact` the code sees there is no id, hence creates a new instance of `Contact` to pass it into a form. Once it comes back as POST, it creates again a new instance of `Contact` and passes it into the form incl. the request.POST. This looks a bit confusing to me, why we create a new instance of Contact and pass it again into the POST form.

Comment: It's just to simplify the pattern - otherwise you need an extra if/else around both form instantiations. It's just an unsaved instance in any case, so there's no db call.

Answer (score 2):

I must be missing something here but why don't you encode the id in the url as is standard?

i.e. in `urls.py`:

```
url('^/contact/?P<contact_id>[0-9]+)/edit/$', edit_contact_view, name='edit_contact_view')
```

your view:

```
def edit_contact_view(request, contact_id):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, id=contact_id)
    if contact not in profile.company.contact_set.all():
        return Http404
```

and in your template

```
<form method="POST">
   {{ form.as_p }}
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: i believe
`get_object_or_404(profile.company.contact_set.all(), id=contact_id)`
should be
`get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=contact_id)`

Comment: good point - get_object_or_404 takes a model class, not a queryset.

Comment: also I use pk instead of id or whatever you may haver overridden your primary key to be, just a tiny bit less model dependent. in general i agree with your approach however. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165865/django-queries-id-vs-pk)

Comment: Actually `get_object_or_404` *can* take a queryset.